# How to get the type of RuntimePropertyInfo

Tags: vb.net, system.reflection

I need to check ***null*** values on several objects, I create a function to iterate through propertys and check values, but I need the type before replacing the value.

```
Private Function EmptyToNulls(ByRef objeto As Object) As Boolean

        For Each PropertyInfo In objeto.GetType().GetProperties()
            If PropertyInfo.GetType().Name = "String" Then
                If IsNothing(PropertyInfo.GetValue(objeto, Nothing)) Then
                    PropertyInfo.SetValue(objeto, "")
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Function
```

The problem is that I´m getting "RuntimePropertyInfo" on

```
PropertyInfo.GetType().Name
```

How can I get correctly the type of the property?

Comment: [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably what you are looking for

Comment: @Plutonix yeap, that make it. Thanks